# DateFormat в Java

Tags: java, дата, парсер, locale, simpledateformat

```
String a= "22-Серпня-2015 22:25:36 ";
Locale loc_ukr = new Locale("uk", "UA");
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",loc_ukr);

Date date = format.parse(a);
System.out.print(date);
```

как мне вывести дату чтобы в консоли выводило по-украински?

Comment: А что происходит сейчас? В чем проблема с кодом?

Comment: `Locale("uk", "UA")` - это что-то новенькое :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используя Java 8 Date and Time API:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "22-Серпня-2015 22:25:36";
    Locale loc_ukr = new Locale("uk", "UA");

    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", loc_ukr);
    System.out.println(dtf.parse(a.toLowerCase()).toString());
}
```

Результат:

```
{},ISO resolved to 2015-08-22T22:25:36
```

Не забывайте, что pattern чувствителен к регистру и без a.toLowerCase() не распарсится.

Answer (score -1):

ИМХО, Вам нужно создать свой Locale, и копать в DateFormatSymbols, т.к. этот класс дает информацию про формат чисел, дат и т.д.

Класс Locale просто хранит информацию о Locale (страна, язык).